# By using setters in model class Saved data is saved repeatedly?

Tags: java, setter

By using setters and getters class, I am setting values to `MusicDetailsObject(pojo class)` when setting first value it is set, then setting second value it is set and also replacing first value and so on...... setting values using loop:

```
   for(int k=0;k<songs.length();k++)
                {
                JSONObject songObject = songs.getJSONObject(k);
                //mName.add(songObject.getString("name"));
                mObject.setmName(songObject.getString("name"));
                //mURL .add(songObject.getString("url"));
                mObject.setmURL(songObject.getString("url"));
                //mListId .add(songObject.getString("id"));
                mObject.setmID(songObject.getString("id"));
                mAlbumList.add(mObject);
                }
```

first time setting values as

```
array1{id = 101
name = Jigarthanda}
```

When setting value second time it showing like this:

```
array1{id = 102
name = Mundasupatti}, array1{id = 102
name = Mundasupatti}
```

so, please let me know how to set  an individual value.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that, inside the loop, you never create a new instance of `mObject`, so the only instance you have is getting reused.

```
for(int k=0;k<songs.length();k++){
  JSONObject songObject = songs.getJSONObject(k);
  mObject = new MyObject() // -> NOW you are assigning values to a different instance.
  //mName.add(songObject.getString("name"));
  mObject.setmName(songObject.getString("name"));
  //mURL .add(songObject.getString("url"));
  mObject.setmURL(songObject.getString("url"));
  //mListId .add(songObject.getString("id"));
  mObject.setmID(songObject.getString("id"));
  mAlbumList.add(mObject);
}
```